# How to prevent split inside a Jasper Report List Element?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have textfields in a JasperReport List elements.
How to prevent textfields to split inside the List elements if textfields stretch to the new page?
I try to use splitType=Prevent in detail band but the whole records inside the List element split to the new page.
I just want the List to prevent split per line record.

Comment: try unchecking stretch with overflow for text field property.

Comment: sorry, my textfield may need to stretch if there are more contents in the textfield

Comment: please show me some screenshots.